# Angular - I'm using YouTube player API. I want refresh component with reloading page

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtubeplayer

I created a simple application about my work and I am using YouTube player API to play/embed my work videos. All I want is to play random videos every time I visit my portfolio page without reloading. And also I want use play/pause events provided by API, like if video is playing I want to give some tips in below with `<p>` tag. I'm working with Ionic and I'm using `ionViewWillEnter() {}` lifecycle to play random videos every time I visit my page.

Here is my code.

**portfolio-page.html**

`<div>` 
`<iframe [src]="randomURL" id="video"></iframe>`
`<p>{{ tips }}</p>`
`</div>`

**portfolio-page.ts**

`ionViewDidEnter() {`
`this.tips = "Some tips here"`
`this.randomURL = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/"my random video URL";`

`// Play Pause events`
`window['onYouTubeIframeAPIReady'] = (e) => {`
`this.YT = window['YT'];`
`this.player = new window['YT'].Player('player', {`
`videoId: id,`
`events: {`
`'onStateChange': (event) => {`
`switch (event.data) {`
`case window['YT'].PlayerState.PLAYING:`
`this.tip = "Some tips here"`
`break;`

but the problem here is When I visit the page for first time, play pause events work perfectly. if visit the page again play pause events are not working. All i want to do here is to refresh component page(i.e HTML page) only without reloading.

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

1. resolver to generate randomURL and populate component before it will load.

   app-routing.ts

   ```
    RouterModule.forRoot([
        {
           path: '/portfolio',
           component: PortfolioPageComponent,
           resolve: { randomURL: PortfolioResolver }
          }
        ])
    ])
   ```

portfolio-resolver.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Resolve } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

export class PortfolioResolver implements Resolve<any> {
  constructor() {}

  resolve(): Observable<any> {
    //generate randomURL
    return randomURL
  }
}
```

portfolio-page.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({ ... })
export class PortfolioPageComponent implements OnInit {
  data: any;
  randomUrl: any;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.data = this.route.snapshot.data;
    this.randomUrl = this.data.randomURL;
    // do what you need with new random url
  }
}
```

2. simply pass some variable as a flag from parent to child component (or from another place via `this.router.navigate(['/portfolio', { reload: true }]);`)  and receive like `this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('reload');` to notify when it must be reloaded.

Comment: hi, I want to refresh my entire page without reloading (`window.localtion.reload`). and  thanks for help

Comment: hi, what's the problem with the methods above? Without page refreshing, you need manually to refetch or recalculate the data and update every component view. With these methods, you can notify components to use new data(randomUrl), or I misunderstood you.